# Confused how to use Variable Effect extra

Tags: wild-talents

Reading the text in the Extras chapter and the example for Cosmic Power in the Miracle Cafeteria has left me confused as to how the Wild Talents extra Variable Effect is supposed to work.

Let's assume the character Doctor Voodoo has 5d + 2wd in Cosmic Power, as in the Miracle Cafeteria chapter. After reading Extras, I assumed the Variable Effect would go:

1. I declare my intent to use Variable Effect
2. I roll 5d + 2wd and necessarily succeed (I assume that in order to succeed this part, I need only make at least one set with a width of 2, so success is guaranteed i.e. height is irrelevant. Please correct this assumption if it's wrong)
3. I decide to set aside 3d + 1wd for a power with, say, 4 levels of Booster to range. This costs me (3+4)*4=28 Willpower. I don't need to roll for this, since I already succeeded in activating Variable Effect
4. Next turn I can use this new power by rolling 3d + 1wd

However, the example in the Miracle Cafeteria chapter reads more like:

1. I declare my intent to use Variable Effect for a new power, one which will have 3d + 1wd
2. I remove these dice from my pool, leaving 2d + 1wd
3. I decide I want 4 levels of Booster to range on this new power. I now roll to activate Variable Effect, which requires a success on 2d + 1wd and costs (2+4)*4=24 Willpower (again I assume this means success is guaranteed, since I'll have at least one set with width 2 and height is irrelevant)
4. Next turn I can use my new power by rolling 3d + 1wd

Which is the correct option? The first way makes more sense to me, since the Willpower is spent on the dice used for the new power and you don't need to spend it if you fail to use Variable Effect, but the second way is how the example in the rulebook demonstrates things.

I'd be inclined to think that there was just a misprint in the example made, but since the Willpower calculation is also not what I expected I feel like I must have missed a rule about this somewhere or that the rulebook is not consistent

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the Essential Edition has to say (p 130):

> You may add Extras and Power Quality Levels to an emulated power by paying Willpower equal to their Point value.
>   For example: let's say you emulate a 4d Attacks power and you add the Extra No Upward Limits and three Attacks levels. No Upward Limit costs +2 Points per die and three Attacks quality levels cost +3 per die. To add them to the emulated power costs 5 Willpower per emulated die, or 20 Willpower for a 4d power.
>   You may reduce the Willpower cost of adding Extras and quality levels to an emulated power effect by adding Flaws to it, to a minimum Willpower cost of 0.

You don't mention whether you're using first or second edition; Essentials is a cut-down version of second edition.

So, let's go to the example of Prince Voodoo using his Loa Power. Where it mentions the Willpower cost (p 144), it says:

> Prince Voodoo takes four levels of Booster on Spy On Distant Enemy's range capacity, for +4 Points per die, to give it a range of about 50 miles (80 km.). For 2d+1wd, that costs 24 Willpower with a successful roll to activate Loa Power.

So, the 24 Willpower is for 2d+1wd... not for the 3d+1wd that was mentioned earlier in the example. This appears to me to be a thinko on the part of the writers, possibly exacerbated in editing by the two mentions of the dice being used being split across a page break.

As I see it, the example is saying that: 2d+1wd = 6d "worth" (since 1wd costs the same as 4d). This is multiplied by the 4 points per die for Boost, for 24 Willpower cost.

If the example had continued with the 3d+1wd, then the cost would have been 28 Willpower, as you calculate. It appears to me that the writers "forgot" that 3d+1wd was the amount they were putting into the power before, looked up and saw the 2d+1wd that's mentioned on the page with the Willpower calculation, and used that instead by accident.

Having written a few game books now myself, I can testify that these kinds of mistakes do happen quite easily! While you're reading it in one go, these power descriptions may have been written across several editing passes, often weeks apart!